# Lipschitz function and gradient.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\phi:U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function ($ U$ is open). We suppose that $\phi$ is smooth in $U\setminus K$, where $K$ has null measure in $U$ and that there exists $C>0$ such that $\|\mbox{Grad}\:\phi(x)\| \leq C$, $x \in U\setminus K$.  Does it mean that $\phi$ is a Lipschitz function?

Comment: Can you say why you think it's true?  Show what you've done to conclude that, perhaps?  As it stands this doesn't seem to ask a question, just make an observation.

Comment: Lipschitz where? How is smoothness defined if $K$ is not closed?

Comment: Dear Kavi, Lipschitz in U (the source of $\phi$)

Comment: Once a time that the Gradient is well defined in $U-K$ its follows that $K$ is closed. Smooth here  means C^1, for instance.

Comment: Is $K$ compact?